# Get weighted value of pandas string series

Tags: python, string, pandas, count, counter

The Series is as below:

```
value
aa aa bb cc
dd ee aa
ff aa cc
```

I want to count the occurrence of a word in the row and multiply it with weight given in the dictionary

```
weights = {
   'aa':1,
   'bb':1,
   'cc':0.5
}
```

The resultant should be

```
value_score
3.5
1
1.5
```

Above could be explained as sum(occurrence of word in dictionary * weight from dictionary) i.e for first value it is 2*1 + 1*1 + 1*0.5 = 3.5

I have currently implemented using str.count, but as more values come in, it is not efficent

```
df['value_score'] = (df['value'].str.count('aa', regex=False) * weights['aa'] +
                     df['value'].str.count('bb', regex=False) * weights['bb'] +
                     df['value'].str.count('cc', regex=False) * weights['cc'] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `get` for `0` for unmatched values:

```
df['value_score'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: sum(weights.get(y, 0) for y in x.split()))
print (df)
         value  value_score
0  aa aa bb cc          3.5
1     dd ee aa          1.0
2     ff aa cc          1.5
```

Another solution:

```
df['value_score'] = df['value'].str.split(expand=True).stack().map(weights).sum(level=0)
print (df)
         value  value_score
0  aa aa bb cc          3.5
1     dd ee aa          1.0
2     ff aa cc          1.5
```

Comment: Is there anyway that it could be done using pandas inbuilt functions.

Comment: @Vishnudev - unfortunately not.

Comment: I have a large dataframe and the above is a bit slow. Is there something I could do for making it efficient

Comment: @Vishnudev - I think if use `apply` it should be slowier a bit, do you test it?

Comment: I did test it. It took out some seconds on overall run.

Comment: the latter solution doesn't seem to work for me. I get all empty values. Do i need to reset the index?

Comment: @Vishnudev - What about `df['value_score'] = df['value'].str.split(expand=True).stack().map(weights).fillna(0).sum(level=0)` ? It not working with sample data too?

Comment: It works on the sample data, but can't figure out why it's not working with my data. Even fillna gives all nan values

Comment: I'll figure it out. Thanks for the answer and support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

df['value_score'] = [sum(weights.get(k, 0) * v for k, v in Counter(x.split()).items()) \
                     for x in df['value']]

print(df)

         value  value_score
0  aa aa bb cc          3.5
1     dd ee aa          1.0
2     ff aa cc          1.5
```

No vectorised solution is possible. For performance, you should favour list comprehensions instead of Pandas `str` methods.